# safeAreaLayoutGuide height returns incorrect value in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I'm trying to position a stack view inside scroll view using top constraints as shown in screenshot below. I want to position stack view in middle by default. I'll change it's value to when keyboard shows and when kb hides set it back to default in center.

It doesn't position exactly in vertically center in simulator. Is there a way to fix it? Or may be I'm doing it wrong?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.topConstraints.constant = self.view.safeAreaFrameFromWindow.height*0.5 - self.stackView.frame.size.height*0.5
}

extension UIView {
    public var safeAreaFrameFromWindow: CGRect {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
            return window.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        }
        return bounds
    }
}
```

[image: view]

Comment: Whats wrong with this..?? its totally working fine

Comment: It doesn't work fine for me in simulator as you can see in the screenshot on right side. It should be vertically in center in simulator.

Comment: @Raymond - are you still having trouble getting your view vertically centered?

Comment: Yes, it's freaking me out. For some reason and no matter which way I try, it doesn't stick to the center after hiding keyboard it shifts down off center. I tried stack view, and even without stack view, same result. And in simulator it doesn't even in the center on first load.

Comment: @Raymond - not sure why you're still having issues... Take another look at my GitHub repo: https://github.com/DonMag/CenteredScroll  I updated it to handle adjusting the scroll view when showing / hiding the keyboard.

Comment: @DonMag It is working now on devices. I can see how you make it worked. I've been struggling for so long and almost gave up on it. Thank you very much for taking so much time to fix this issue. I appreciate that. Just last thing, why it doesn't center vertically in simulator see this https://imgur.com/a/6zufPFl

Comment: @Raymond - ah... just noticed from your image that you're running this on Simulator iPhone 5s with **iOS 10.3.1** -- in Storyboard, select the view controller and **un-check** `Adjust Scroll View Insets` https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQW07.png

Comment: It resolves all issues now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Raymond - as a side note, supporting back to iOS 10 is unusual, unless you have a very specific reason.

Comment: I need that, I've $$$$$ on stake. Some customers can't seem to upgrade to latest versions. Can't lose them. Every $ counts on live app :)